# How to restrict description for 2digits only

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to validate my description text-area for the text in that will contain only 2 or **less than 2 digits**.It will include text also.I have tried with `**regex**` but I have no result.I have tried like

```
if(value.match(/^\d{1,2}$/)){
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

Means

**Valid :**

```
this is 22 years old
```

**In Valid :**

```
this is 222 years old
```

Can anyone suggest me any solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The regexp is fine for what you want to do. But how are you using it ? Show us your code please.

Comment: Is value supposed to be "this is 22 years old" or "this is 222 years old" ?

Comment: Ok see answer from @Salketer, you don't want to be using ^ and $ here.

Comment: Just found an ambiguity... Is it 2 digits total in the whole text? See bottom of my answer

Comment: No..I want to restrict the 2 digits if they are continuous only...Your ans is correct.."I am 24 and my brother is 29" will be valid but "Iam 100 years old" will be error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any implementing code it is hard to say...

But you'll want to remove the `^` and `$` from your regex, they state begining and end of the string respectively.

You'd be better on trying to find numbers of more than 2 digits and return true if found:

```
/\d{3,}/
```

This will be true for all strings that include numbers of 3 digits so you know it is not good.

EDIT:

```
if(!value.match(/\d{3,}/)){
    return false;
}else{
    return true;
}
//Or, as Julian Descottes *almost* pointed out, simply return the value of the function
return !!value.match(/\d{3,}/);
```

Re-reading OP, I am not sure if this is exactly the expected behaviour as it checks for NUMBERS of 3digits or more, but does not count the amount of digits in the text allowing

```
I am 24 and my brother is 29
```

This has 4 digits, should it be good or bad?

Comment: You could return `!!value.match(/\d{3,}/)` directly here though :)

Comment: Isn't it the other way around, like `if(value.match(/\d{3,}/)) { return false; }`? [See](http://jsfiddle.net/LUART/)

Comment: @Salketer `value.match` doesn't return a boolean but an object. Not sure that's what is expected as a return value of this function. Hence my proposal using `!!`

Comment: Actually we should use /\d{3,}/.test(value) here

Comment: Unless there is a big performance impact, I don't see why that would be better?

Comment: The initial function was returning true or false. I'm just trying to stick to this contract since I have no idea how the return value is used in the rest of the code. 

And using `test` is the easiest way to get a boolean here.

Answer (score -2):

`^\d{1,2}$` won't match any text, but it will match both the start and end of the string. So, it will match **"34"** but not **"1934"** or **"Babylon 5"**.

What you probably want is `^\D*\d{1,2}\D*$`. The flanking **\D*'s** mean "match 0 to an infinite number of non-digit characters."

Comment: Would fail on string "I am 22 years old and my brother is 29"

Comment: "I am 2 years old and my brother is 9" has 2 and fails. I was thinking that it should only allow 1-2 digit numbers, not total amount in the text.